# Plotting based on Values in Data Frame: Python Pandas

Tags: python, time, plot, pandas, series

I am just starting to look into time series and using python and the built in functions of pandas to plot data.

I have my own dataframe where I have a 'Date' and 'Prices'

```
Creation Date        Price
1/1/2013              2.0
1/2/2013              5.0
1/3/2013              6.0
1/4/2013              9.0

etc
```

I am trying to use

```
ts= Series(df['Price'], index = date_range('1/1/2013', periods =100)
```

I am not getting any values in my graph/plot, just an empty graph from .6 to -.6 and the dates on the bottom.

I am thinking that the graph doesn't recognize the Date column as actual dates... not sure why else it wouldn't work.

How can I graph the prices according the date values that I have in the columns?

UPDATES:

I realize that if I create a series like:

```
 ts= Series(df['Price'], index = df['Creation Date']
```

I get:

```
Creation Date
1/31/2014       NaN
1/31/2014       NaN

 etc...
```

Whereas if I create a series such as:

```
ts2= Series(df['Price'])
```

This yields:

```
   0      81.849998
   1      41.220001
   2      22.049999
   3      10.770000
   4      17.790001
   .... etc.
```

So I am getting the prices but not the dates for one series and the dates but NaN values for another series....

Comment: Can you provide a complete code snippet?  I.e. the code to produce appropriate test data followed by the command that produces unacceptable output?

Answer (score 2):

Why bother making the series at all?

```
newdf = df[['Price', 'Creation Date']].set_index('Creation Date')
newdf.plot()
```

Or as an alternative:

```
df.plot('Price', 'Creation Date')
```